# Simple Picasso Call doesn't work

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to use Picasso in my application and am running the simple experiment below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();//prints name of class without package name

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);

        swap(image1);
    }

    public void swap(ImageView image){
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("") // IMAGE URL HERE
                .skipMemoryCache()
                .fit()
                .into(image);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have 7 imageviews in my layout and I just want to see if I can use picasso to fill up all 7 of them from 7 different web urls.  In the above script, I'm trying to get picasso to replace even 1 of those image views, but it won't do it.  The app shows the 7 initial image views but doesn't swap them out for the image in the URL.  There are surprisingly no console messages either.

Comment: How do you expect to replace?

Comment: Shouldn't picasso replace the imageview I pass onto it?

Comment: If by replace you mean load bitmap inside it, yes, it should. If you think it should load one image and replace to the others, no, thats not possible just by calling Picasso on one `ImageView`

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the Picasso library, but it is possible you still need to `invalidate()` the image or request a layout change.  It is unsure what they might be doing under the covers.

Comment: I am currently trying to replace even the one image, but it isn't working and I can't figure out why.